# Is it legal for an apartment or county or state to ignore fire safety rules?

Tags: united-states, georgia, safety

(Jurisdiction: GA, USA)

My apartment's elevator inspection certificate has expired 3 months ago.  This puts serious risk on lives on residents especially in the high-rise.

I've sent multiple reminders to the maintainence staff about this but no progress. There's nothing about this being their responsibility in the lease agreement either.

Apparently the government database about all this is not functioning.

Is it legally alright to ignore fire safety rules?  If not, whose responsibility is this - the apartment's, county's or state's?

(Apartment=Landlord)

Comment: Maintenance staff can not certify the elevator. As a tenant you can not order an inspection, only the owner of the elevator can. There is no central government database on elevator certificates.

Comment: @Trish I am referring to this: https://www.wrdw.com/2021/10/18/georgia-cant-yet-track-elevators-that-are-overdue-inspection/

Comment: Obviously, it isn't legally O.K. to ignore a law. The relevant question is really what options or remedies you have if an apartment manager's failure to comply.

Comment: @ohwilleke The question is whose responsibility it is to comply with the rules? Is it the government's or the apartment's? Its not straightforward...

Comment: @IñakiViggers please add your answer to chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149794/law-se-97328

Answer (score 1):

#### Contact the Georgia State Fire Marshall

Owners of elevator must maintain current inspections.  You can make a complaint to the fire marshal.

[GA OCI](https://oci.georgia.gov/inspections-permits-plans/elevators-escalators)

[GA Elevator rules & regs](https://rules.sos.ga.gov/gac/120-3-25)